Disposal of Attic insulation material (Fiber Glass)
How to dispose old attic insulation material (fiberglass) in San Diego?
Can I bag it in plastic bag and put it into waste bin ?

You need to ask the locals in charge of waste, but I do not know why not.  It might be better as construction waste, since batts take a lot of room.  You might get two or three batts in a bag(big bag).

https://wastefreesd.org/ and see what they can do with fiberglass insulation.

@crip659 if you get them wet they'll take up less space. Of course, they'll also weigh more! :D

...don't dispose of it? It doesn't "wear out" with age, so "old insulation" is still insulation. If you want more insulation, add more, leaving this in place. Or do you have a thing against insulation at all, so you're just removing it to have none?

@Ecnerwal  It doesn't wear out, but it can get dirty, moldy, etc.
